# R: function 'save' changes the arrays to a function

Tags: r, package, save

I defined a function in my package to save some arrays into a Rdata file. After running the function and loading the saved file, I saw two arrays were changed to a function.

If I use the function outside of the package (defining the function code in R) everything works properly. I know the issue is the name of the arrays but I wonder why it happens.

Here is the function that I defined in my package:

```
#' @export
make_name_save <- function(File_name_val = NULL){
  file_full_name = paste(File_name_val,'_',Sys.Date(),'.Rdata', sep = '')
  simulated_df = list(Im = Im, I = I, S = S)
  if( !file.exists(file_full_name) ){
    #save(Im, I, S, file = file_full_name), # writing in this way also yields the same issue. 
    save(simulated_df, file = file_full_name)
  }else{
    print("file is exiseted")
  }
  return()
}
```

and here is the code that I run to save the file, "I" and "Im" will change to a function.

```
rm(list = ls())
devtools::document()
devtools::load_all()
I = array(0, c(42,19,365))
S = Im = matrix(0, ncol = 19, nrow = 365)
test::make_name_save('df')
load('df_2023-06-29.Rdata')
simulated_df
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: `I` and `Im` are both base functions. If you want to save the objects you've created with the same names as these base functions, you should design your function to accept them as arguments and pass the objects in explicitly so that you call your function as `make_save_name('df', I = I, Im = S)`. When you pass things as arguments there is less ambiguity about where they come from - your working environment, loaded namespaces, or anywhere else.

Comment: Further, defining a package function that assumes the existence of objects in the calling environment and namespace-search, you introduce many avenues of problem: difficulty troubleshooting, inconsistent behavior, etc. Your function performance would likely be much clearer if you don't use names of preexisting base objects such as the functions `I` and `Im` (as Gregor said). For instance, naming an object you assume to work as `mtcars` or `iris` is clearly not a good idea, as those are both frames _and are always guaranteed to exist_, so why would one do it with function names?

Comment: Change your function to be something like `make_name_save <- function(File_name_val = NULL, ...) { simulated_df = list(...); ...; }` and call it as GregorThomas said. Note that you will need to name them when you _call_ it so that they are appropriately named in the `list` and therefore within the `.Rdata` file. It's fine in general to not name them (both for `simulated_df` and for `save`, though in the context of what I think you're doing, you want to have the names preserved.